# accordion selector in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, pdf, iframe

I have an accordion that I have created to have certain selected pdf's to show.
I then added an iframe on the same page to show the selected pdf next to it.

I then tried to add some javascript  code to load into the iframe to pick which the user has selected to show the correct pdf. It does not seem to work though.

I have linked my code pen project for the code here: https://codepen.io/Si24/pen/KrprRN

```
html:

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
  <title>What to Say Dialogues</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../App_Themes/Dialogue/WhatToSay.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <form id="WhatToSay" runat="server">
    <div class="wrap">
      <section class="dialogue-section">
        <h1>Dialogues</h1>

        <!-- beginning of prospecting section-->
        <div class="dial-section-1">
          <input id="dial-1" type="radio" name="tabs" tabindex="1" />
          <label for="dial-1">Prospecting</label>

          <div class="dial-wrap">

            <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-2" type="radio" name="prospecting-tab-one" tabindex="3" />
              <label for="sections-2">Cold Calling - Offer of Information</label>
              <p class="result">A Reason to call : Making market information available to a prospect so as to gain an appointment as well as have a reason to keep in touch.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-7" type="radio" name="prospecting-tab-one" tabindex="8" />
              <label for="sections-7">People you may know</label>
              <p class="result">A Reason to call :
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-8" type="radio" name="prospecting-tab-one" tabindex="9" />
              <label for="sections-8">Pre Qualifying</label>
              <p class="result">A Reason to call :
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-9" type="radio" name="prospecting-tab-one" tabindex="10" />
              <label for="sections-9">Show House</label>
              <p class="result">A Reason to call: Letting the neighbours know that there is a show house in there vicinity so as to qualify and get an appointment.</p>
            </div>
             <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-12" type="radio" name="prospecting-tab-one" tabindex="13" />
              <label for="sections-12">OPT in Follow Up</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of prospecting Dialogue section-->
        <div class="dial-section-2">
          <input id="dial-2" type="radio" name="tabs" tabindex="14" />
          <label for="dial-2">Listing</label>

          <div class="dial-wrap">
            <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-13" type="radio" name="questions-tab-two" tabindex="15">
              <label for="sections-13">Pre Qualifying</label>
              <!-- end of question label -->
            </div>
            <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-15" type="radio" name="questions-tab-two" tabindex="17">
              <label for="sections-15">Listing Presentation</label>
              <!-- end of question label -->
              <p class="result">Presentation: Getting the Listing using trusted methods such as confirmation of Reason and Motivation, establishing market value (Price) and getting the mandate.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-16" type="radio" name="questions-tab-two" tabindex="18">
              <label for="sections-16">Intelligent Pricing</label>
              <!-- end of question label -->
              <p class="result">Pricing: A visual and easy interactive way of showing how incorrect pricing affects buyer interest.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-17" type="radio" name="questions-tab-two" tabindex="19">
              <label for="sections-17">Reality Check</label>
              <!-- end of question label -->
              <p class="result">The Competition: A visual picture showing stock availability, competition and what’s happening in the market.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-18" type="radio" name="questions-tab-two" tabindex="20">
              <label for="sections-18">How to Fill in the Reality Check Sheet</label>
              <!-- end of question label -->
              <p class="result">The Competition: How to use the Reality check sheet to show stock availability, competition and what’s happening in the market as well as where the data comes from.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dial-section-3">
          <input id="dial-3" type="radio" name="tabs" tabindex="21" />
          <label for="dial-3">CMA prospecting - Video / SMS</label>

          <div class="dial-wrap">
            <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-19" type="radio" name="questions-tab-two" tabindex="22">
              <label for="sections-19">Video Dialogue</label>
              <!-- end of question label -->
              <p class="result">A Reason to call: To confirm an appointment already made but not yet pre-qualified for, to find out how Motivated they are and Reason for selling.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-20" type="radio" name="questions-tab-two" tabindex="23">
              <label for="sections-20">Video Dialogue</label>
              <!-- end of question label -->
              <p class="result">Pre Listing Package Suggestions: Some suggestions for inclusion in you pre Appointment Listing Package icluding various reports from CMAInfo.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-21" type="radio" name="questions-tab-two" tabindex="24">
              <label for="sections-21">Sample YouTube Video</label>
              <!-- end of question label -->
              <p class="result">Presentation: Getting the Listing using trusted methods such as confirmation of Reason and Motivation, establishing market value (Price) and getting the mandate.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sections">
              <input id="sections-22" type="radio" name="questions-tab-two" tabindex="25">
              <label for="sections-22">SMS Text..</label>
              <!-- end of question label -->
              <p class="result">Pricing: A visual and easy interactive way of showing how incorrect pricing affects buyer interest.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
       </section>
    </div>
    <div class="split right">
      <iframe id="dialPdf" src="" width="50%"> </iframe>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>

Css :

    body {
    -webkit-animation:bugfix infinite 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bugfix {
    from {padding:0;}
    to {padding:0;}
}

body{

    background:radial-gradient(ellipse fartherst-side as 100% 100%,#d4faf6 1%,#85d8ce 30%,#085078 120%);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    padding-top:2em;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

.split{
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.left{
    left:0;
}

.right{
    right:0;
}

.wrap {
    display:block;
    max-width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto 2em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    /*width:100%;*/
}

@media(min-width:43.75em)
{
    .wrap{
        padding:3em;
    }
}

p{
    color:#555;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
    margin-left:2em;
}

a, a:visited{
    color:#4bc5b7;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.dialogue-section{
    background:#f1f1f1;
    box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(68,68,0.4);
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 1em;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align:top;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 50em){
    .dialogue-section{
        font-size:0.75rem;
        padding:1em 1.5em;
    }
}

@media (min-width:62.5em){
    .dialogue-section{
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
}

.dialogue-section h1{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#085078;
    font-size:1.25em;
    font-size:5.5vw;
    font-weight:700;
    margin-bottom:0.25em;
}

@media (min-width:32.25em){
    .dialogue-section h1{
        font-size:3.25em;
        font-size:4.9vw;
    }
}

.dialogue-section > p, .dialogue-section >h1 {
    text-align:center;
}

.dialogue-section > p {
    font-size:0.667em;
    font-size:2.8vw;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}

@media (min-width:22.1875em){
    .dialogue-section > p{
        font-size:0.667em;
    }
}

@media(min-width:31.25em){
    .dialogue-section > p{
        font-size:1em;
    }
}

@media(min-width:81.25em){
    .dialogue-section > p{
        font-size:1.15em;
    }
}

div[class^=dial] {
    width: 100%;
}

div[class^=dial] > label {
    background: #2980b9;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.75em 0.5em;
    transition: all 0.55s;
}

div[class^= dial] > label:hover {
    background: #41b9ff;
}

@media (min-width:50em){
    div[class^=dial] > label{
        font-size:1.25em;
    }
}

div[class^=dial] > input {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -999;
}

div[class^= dial] > input:focus + label {
    background:#41b9ff;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

div[class^=dial].dial-wrap {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.19,1,0.22,1);
    width: 100%;
}

div[class^=dial] > input:checked ~ .dial-wrap {
    max-height: 1000px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1.95s cubic-bezier(0.19,1 0.22,1);
}

.dial-wrap .sections {
    margin: 1em 0;
}

.section{
    margin-left:1em;
}


.dial-wrap label {
    color: #0a6090;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

@media(min-width:50em){
    .dial-wrap label {
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }
}

.dial-wrap input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -999;
    top: -1000px;
}

.dial-wrap input:focus + label {
    color: #064060;
}

.dial-wrap input:not(:checked) ~ p {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.19,1,0.22,1);
}

.dial-wrap input:checked ~ p {
    max-height: 500px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1.95s cubic-bezier(0.19,1,0.22,1);
}

input:focus{
    border:3px solid red;
    outline:3px solid red;
    background:red;
}

a:focus {
    color:#085078;
    font-weight:bold;
    outline:none;
}

#dialPdf{
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(68,68,0.4);
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    padding:1em 1.5em;
}

and javascript: 


       var docPdf = document.getElementsByClassName("docPdf"); 

        function openPdf() {

            document.getElementById("dialPdf").src = docPdf;

        ////console.log("this is working");
  //document.getElementById("dialPdf").src = "";

        }

any help or info what I'm doing wrong will be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `openPdf` function when you click your accordion with expected url to be load into iframe.

Updated javascript code

```
    function openPdf(url) {
        document.getElementById("dialPdf").src = url;
    }
```

Comment: I think I'm still a little lost. If I physicaly set the url in the src it will work but each pdf has its own unique name. I can start the url src since they are all in the same folder. This is the first time I'm ever using iframes and javascript.

Comment: Attached a click event listeners on each sections `<div class="sections" data-key="cold_calling">` with data-key is set to url of pdf to be load. I have created an codepen ( https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qQZdOG?editors=1010 ) to working demo only for the `Prospecting` sections.